# Using R - Compare differend columns of data frames to a set of valid column combinations

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using **R Studio with R version 3.2.2** and I want to filter for rows in a data frame, where I want to see only those rows, where the combination of values from two columns don't match to a valid combination stored value pairs in a second data frame.
I've heard R is not designed to use loops in a performant way so I'm looking for a solution without using loops, if there are any.

Using this sample data I scaled down, the first data frame *dfItem* contains item IDs and two statuses.

```
> dfItem
  ID Status_1 Status_2
1  1        1        1
2  2        1        2
3  3        2        1
4  4        3        3
5  5        2        3
6  6        1        1
```

Second data frame *dfValidPairs* contains all valid combinations of the two statuses.

```
> dfValidStatus
  Status_1 Status_2
1        1        1
2        1        2
3        3        3
```

How can I check if a status pair from *dfItem*, consisting of *Status_1* and *Status_2*, is in one of the valid statuses from *dfValidPairs*?
In the end I would like to have only the rows from *dfItem* which have an invalid status pair, stored in a new data frame like this.

```
> dfInvalid
  ID Status_1 Status_2
1  3        2        1
2  5        2        3
```

I can only think of for loops which iterate over the data frames. Do you know if there are any more performant possibilities?

Cheers,
Felix

---

code for the objects

```
> dfItem <- data.frame( c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1), c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1) )
> colnames( dfItem ) <- c( "ID", "Status_1", "Status_2" )
> dfValidStatus <- data.frame( c(1, 1, 3), c(1,2,3) )
> colnames( dfValidStatus ) <- c( "Status_1", "Status_2" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of merge - or actually here its opposite:

```
> library(dplyr)
> anti_join(dfItem, dfValidStatus)

Joining by: c("Status_1", "Status_2")
  ID Status_1 Status_2
1  5        2        3
2  3        2        1
```

The other useful merge or set operations are `inner_join`, `left_join`, `right_join` etc

Comment: Hello Stephen, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.